# ASP.NET MVC Inserting object and related object into 2 tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, insert

I have two tables: `Users` and `UserOwners`. Table `UserOwners` contains list of users that certain user created (list of child-users) - or to be more precise, it contains `UserOwnerID` and `UserID` fields.

So, now I want to create a new user... in Controller I have something like this:

```
var userOwner = accountRepository.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
var userOwnerID = userOwner.UserID;

UserReference userReference = new UserReference();
userReference.UserOwnerID = userOwnerID;

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        //accountRepository.Add(user);
        //accountRepository.Save();

        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What is the easiest way to add new user to a table `Users` and matching `UserOwner` to `UserOwners` table.

Is it suppose to be something like this?

```
public void Add(User user)
{
     db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
     db.UserReferences.InsertOnSubmit(user.UserReference);
}

public void Save()
{
     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

...or I will have to pass two objects and after adding user I must read it's ID and than assign it to userReference object and add that object to DB?
If so, how to read ID of the last object added?

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: Can a User have more than one Owner?  Your schema seems a little odd...  I'd assume one owner per user, multiple users per owner, which means OwnerId goes in the Users table and the relationship points to UserId of the Users table.

Comment: The User can have more than one owner

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, just add owner(s) to your customer model as a property.